# Parsing a function like string

Tags: c#, string

I need to parse a string like this in C#:

*GET_VALUE("USER_NAME")*

... and return something like:

*USER 101*

And USER_NAME is one of several properties supported in the system.

I have already done some string parsing to do this.

My question is if there is some good pattern/implementation I should follow that parses the above with better/maintainable code, as well as addressing some future potential enhancements (like supporting operators like +, etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for `eval()` -like functionality, C#'s designers avoided this on purpose. It was a deliberate design decisions, because they had many use cases in mind for the language where this would be a huge gaping security problem. That doesn't mean it's impossible; there are several ways to accomplish this: Roslyn, Reflection.Emit, and System.CodeDom all have some capability in this area, but none of them make it quick or simple.

If you really need to parse code, be aware it's a very slippery slope. Today, they want simple function calls; tomorrow, they'll want full expressions and grammar. You don't want to start from scratch for this. Take a look at lexer/parser libraries like [ANTLR](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs).

The other option is a DSL ([Domain Specific Language](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj5g7Lu8P7TAhWM6oMKHd_LDb8QFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb126278.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFIUS0_gsjcmGQUh8Cysnb1jxc5FA&sig2=zaC8NHHo0v3VqeS-oZ0aCQ)), which lets you define a grammar for your program to parse input into executable code.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is to get the name of who is logged in, try this:

```
string vUserID = (Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]);
```